# Determine the degree of a polynomial using its graph

Tags: polynomials

Today, while repeating for a test at polynomials, this problem has came through my mind. Given the graph of a polynomial $f: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ with integer coefficients, determine its degree. As I am a newbie to polynomials, I don't know a solution to this problem, or even where I should start from.
Does anyone have a solution to this? And if so, could you share it here, please? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... Do you ideally want a solution that analyzes just the graph's shape?

Comment: You can use the coordinates of the graph as well

Answer (score 1):

The brutal way to solve this problem algorithmically would be to try interpolating $(1,f(1)),...,(k,f(k))$. Let's call $p_k$ the interpolating polynomial. If $p_k$ behaves like $f$ on the integer than the degree of $f$ is the degree of $p_k$. If not, just increase the number of points, and eventually this algorithm will end.

A less brutal heuristic way is given by the following observation. The degree $d$ of a polynomial is the only natural number such that the sequence:
$$a_n=f(n)/n^d$$
converges to a non-zero real number as $n$ grows. Clearly you can't calculate this limit exactly if you don't know the expression of $f$, but you can try to extimate it numerically.

I don't think there's much more to be done. Clearly, it's easy to determine from the "drawing of the graph" the parity of the degree (do you see it?).

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to determine the degree of a polynomial using its graphic, is to see the maximum number of points a straight line can intersect the graph. However, it is clear that if the degree is high, this practical rule ceases to be so and the problem escapes from the visual.

Comment: It's even worse than that. Here we have just a discrete subset of the graphic. And moreover even if we had the whole graphic, there could be multiple roots.

Comment: @Kandinskij: That's right. Many situations in maths where a human body can work just with few cases of the same kind (sorry for bad English).